# How to only combine elements of lists that dont give 0 when multiplied with each other

Tags: python, list, multiplication

I would like to only combine elements of lists that dont give 0 when multiplied with each other.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
c = [0, 0, 3, 0, 5]
```

Since 1x10x0 = 0, 2x20x0 = 0, 3x30x3 = 270, 4x40x0 = 0, 5x50x5 = 1250

only combine

```
a = [3, 5]
b = [30, 50]
c = [3, 5]
```

expected output:

```
d = [(3,30,3), (5,50,5)]
```

Comment: You'll need to write code, which you do not appear to have even attempted to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate the lists in parallel.

As you deal with integers, you could use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to identify if you have any zero (in which case the product will be 0):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
c = [0, 0, 3, 0, 5]

d = [x for x in zip(a,b,c) if all(x)]
```

output: `[(3, 30, 3), (5, 50, 5)]`

How it works:

`all` will check if all values in an iterable are truthy. For integers, 0 is the only non truthy value. So `all(list_of_integers)` is `False` if any value is 0, and `True` otherwise.

Alternative syntax:

An alternative syntax could be to use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
d = list(filter(all, zip(a, b, c)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listOfTuples = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    if 0 in [a[i], b[i], c[i]]:
        continue
    else:
        listOfTuples.append((a[i], b[i], c[i]))

print(list)
```

Comment: Do not use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
c = [0, 0, 3, 0, 5]
final_ouput=[(x,y,z) for x,y,z in zip(a,b,c) if x * y* z !=0]
```

Output

```
[(3, 30, 3), (5, 50, 5)]
```